# apply hover effect on div but not on h2 inside this

Tags: html, css

When you hover on `div`, `background-color` applies to entire `div`. I want to exclude `h2` and I want to keep the `h2` text black without background color.

```
<style>
  .Blog-header-content:hover {
    background: rgb(237, 177, 196) none repeat scroll 0 0 important;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }

  h2 {
    color: #000;
  }
</style>


<div class="Blog-header-content">
  hihihihhihhihihihhiihhihih
  <h2 class="Blog-title">helloooooooooooooo</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/xst8uupj/)?

Comment: no,please don't modify my  code..keep my code and just show h2 in black color..I don't need color on h2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, all `<h></h>` tags are inside the `<div></div>` tag  and when you fade its opacity, the **texts** fades too.

here is a trick to do the the same thing without fading the text.. just remove the opacity tag from div and add  opacity to colors.

**To show `<h2>` tag without fade**

just change `rgb(237, 177, 196)` to `rgb(237, 177, 196,.4)` and remove `opacity(0.4)`  hope this will work

```css
.Blog-header-content:hover{  background: rgba(237, 177, 196,.4) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important ;}
h2{color:#000;}
```

```html
<div class="Blog-header-content">
hihihihhihhihihihhiihhihih
<h2 class="Blog-title">helloooooooooooooo</h2>
</div>
```

**If you want to show `h2` tag without background color then just put it outside that `div` tag**

```css
.Blog-header-content:hover{  background: rgba(237, 177, 196,.4) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important ;}
h2{color:#000;}
```

```html
<div class="Blog-header-content">
hihihihhihhihihihhiihhihih

</div>
<h2 class="Blog-title">helloooooooooooooo</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks,rgb(237, 177, 196) to rgb(237, 177, 196,.4) This code works

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use this to remove background from h2 on hover on div

```css
.Blog-header-content:hover{  background: rgb(237, 177, 196) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important ;opacity:0.4;}
.Blog-header-content:hover h2{  background: #fff!important ;}
h2{color:#000;}
```

```html
<div class="Blog-header-content">
hihihihhihhihihihhiihhihih
<h2 class="Blog-title">helloooooooooooooo</h2>
</div>
```

but when it comes on opacity if you reduce opacity of main div then the child elements will also use the parent's opacity.

So if possible you can do it with a bit of html change like this

```css
.Blog-header-content:hover{  background: rgb(237, 177, 196) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important ;}
.Blog-header-content:hover span{ opacity:0.4;}
.Blog-header-content:hover h2{  background: #fff!important ;}
h2{color:#000;}
```

```html
<div class="Blog-header-content">
<span>hihihihhihhihihihhiihhihih</span>
<h2 class="Blog-title">helloooooooooooooo</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: but i need background color behind the h2 ..actually i have blog website..there is text on image..i want apply color with opacity on image but not on h2

Comment: in your question you said that you need to keep h2 text black without background color

Answer (score 0):

If you change parent `opacity`, child opacity property will be from its parent `opacity`. Eg:

```
parent{opacity:0.8;}
child{opacity:0.8;} // that's means it is 0.8 of parent opacity, so it's 0.64
```

So i sugget if it's possible to wrap other content in additional tag, and add `opacity` attribute to it & additionally set background for h1:

```css
.Blog-header-content:hover{  background: rgba(237, 177, 196,0.4) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important ;}
.Blog-header-content:hover p {opacity:0.4}
h2{color:#000;background:#fff;}
```

```html
<div class="Blog-header-content">
<p>hihihihhihhihihihhiihhihih</p>
<h2 class="Blog-title">helloooooooooooooo</h2>
</div>
```

Or just set background only for new tag:

```css
.Blog-header-content:hover p {opacity:0.4;background: rgb(237, 177, 196) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important ;}
h2{color:#000;}
```

```html
<div class="Blog-header-content">
<p>hihihihhihhihihihhiihhihih</p>
<h2 class="Blog-title">helloooooooooooooo</h2>
</div>
```